IIO period unit
Suppose that we have an accelerometer device that allows to trigger an inactivity interrupt after some period of inactivity.
The device allows to configure inactivity using 8 bit register where scale factor is 1s/LSB.
The IIO subsystem allows then to read / write this value through eg:

iio:device0/events/in_accel_thresh_falling_period

What should be the unit of this value? Is it defined in the kernel, or is it device specific? If my device does not allow to configure inactivity time with granularity finer than 1s, should it be expressed in seconds? Or perhaps microseconds?

Does below answers your question?

Either you have a typo in the output example, or a custom kernel. If the latter is the case you need to ask the vendor of that kernel.
Otherwise the kernel documentation is clear about this:

Period of time (in seconds) for which the condition must be
met before an event is generated. If direction is not
specified then this period applies to both directions.

Just out of curiosity if you need a better granularity for a value, the IIO subsystem provides different markers for the drivers to signal that to the user space, e.g., integer + micro.
